# how to get the name string from a variable or function?

Tags: clojure

I would like to get the name of a variable as a string in Clojure.
However, unlike in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030107/in-clojure-how-to-get-the-name-string-from-a-variable-or-function), I would get the name of the original binding (not sure if the terminology is correct, so please see my example below).

```
(def sample-data1 {:data 1})
(def sample-data2 {:data 2})
(def sample-data3 {:data 3})


(doseq
    [my-var [sample-data1 sample-data2 sample-data3]]
  (println (name 'my-var)))
```

In this case, instead of printing

```
my-var
my-var
my-var
```

I would like to have :

```
sample-data1
sample-data2
sample-data3
```

How do I do that in Clojure ?

*Note :* This is probably not the prettiest thing to do in a real app. But my question is about if this is this possible.

To clarify : this is for prototyping purposes. In this specific case instead of printing I am filling a (postgres) database with fake data that I write by hand in variables, and I'd like to track where my variable end up without writing too much code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`def` creates a var with the same name as the name of the symbol supplied as `def` first parameter. Var in clojure differs from what we usually meant by variable whereas a variable usually can be visualized as a box that contains a value and a var is something that points to a value.

From your example, (here, I am in `user` namespace)

```
user> (def sample-data1 {:data 1})
#'user/sample-data1
```

clojure creates a `#'user/sample-data1` var in `user` namespace which points to `{:data 1}` value. You can get the value back from that newly create var by deref-ing it using `deref` or `@` shorthand.

```
user> (deref #'user/sample-data1)
{:data 1}
user> @#'user/sample-data1
{:data 1}
```

or if you evaluate a symbol, clojure looks up for a var in the current namespace and returns the value pointed by that var.

```
user> sample-data1
{:data 1}
```

you can get a var from a symbol by using `var` for `#'` shorthand.

```
user> (var sample-data1)
#'user/sample-data1
user> #'sample-data1
#'user/sample-data1
```

So, you want the name of the var. The name of the var is contained inside the var's meta data which can be accessed using `meta` applied to a var.

```
user> (meta #'sample-data1)
{:line 1, :column 1, :file "/tmp/form-init3246148490151701909.clj",
 :name sample-data1, :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x39ba2c26 "user"]}
```

Above, you can see that the name of the var is located by `:name` key.

so, you can get the name of a var from its metadata.

```
user=> (:name (meta #'sample-data1))
sample-data1
```

I prefer not to have too many nested parenthesis, so I use thread-first macro `->`

```
user=> (-> #'sample-data1 meta :name)
sample-data1
```

#### the answer

So back to your question, you need the `sample-data[1-3]` vars and their metadata to get their name.

```
(def sample-data1 {:data 1})
(def sample-data2 {:data 2})
(def sample-data3 {:data 3})

(doseq
    [my-var [#'sample-data1 (var sample-data2) #'sample-data3]] 
  (println (-> my-var meta :name)))
```

and the result is

```
sample-data1
sample-data2
sample-data3
nil
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But then how do I get the content of the var ? `(println my-var)` outputs `nil`.

Comment: Correction sorry, it outputs `sample-data1` , etc.  Which is what I asked, but now I don't get why you are using `meta :name`. Also, how can you still access the content (ie `{:data 1}`) ?

Comment: i just updated my answer on why I use `meta :name`. You get the value pointed by a var by using dereference `deref` or `@` to that var (there's a example in my answer above).